# Is it possible to access the raw request XML in JAX-WS without using @WebServiceProvider?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

A JAX-WS service defined using `@WebService` and `@WebMethod` makes use of JAXB to turn the XML into a Java object. For most use cases, this is great!

However, I need to interface with some legacy code written using Axis 1 which exclusively operates on `org.w3c.dom.Element` objects - in other words, I'd effectively just have to transform the parameters straight back into XML as soon as I got them, which seems horrendously inefficient.

Therefore, I've been looking for a way to receive and return raw XML from a JAX-WS service, either just as a string or as objects.

I've been able to get the functionality I need by using `@WebServiceProvider` and implementing the `Provider<Source>` interface, but this feels a little too low-level for the kind of thing I'm doing - I can't use `@WebMethod` to easily set up routing; instead I have to get the `PATH_INFO` from `WebServiceContext` and fiddle with the string to get the information I need.

So my question is, is there a way to make use of raw XML (effectively cutting out JAXB) in a JAX-WS service without dropping down to the `@WebServiceProvider` level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled across the answer by myself, so here it is for anyone else who has this issue:

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_16_1-Elements-With-Any-Type.html), JAXB can marshal `xsd:anyType` into `Object`. The concrete type of the resulting Object is `apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl`, which is an implementation of `org.w3c.dom.Element` - i.e. exactly what I need!

Therefore the solution to my problem was simply to use `Object` as the parameter and return types in my method. Not a massively clean feeling solution, but it works.